# How to resolve a FETCH OUT OF SEQUENCE situation?

Tags: php, oracle

I have the a simple select query in oracle and I want to use a condition for the number of rows returned.

```
oci_execute($query); // The query return 5 rows
//$numrows = oci_num_rows($query);
$numrows = oci_fetch_all($query); // The value of the $numrows is 5
if($numrows>0){  // This condition prompts the **fetch out of sequence** error
    //do something
}else{
    //do something else
}
```

Based on what I have found after some googling, I know it is because the cursor is now located after the last row of the query results (perhaps for counting the rows).

I have temporarily managed this by executing the the query once again right after getting the number of rows. and it seems to work. But I am feeling like fooling myself.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Why not use [oci_num_rows($query)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-num-rows.php) instead of `$numrows = oci_fetch_all($query);`?

Comment: oci_num_rows() returned 0 while that is not correct!

Comment: So if you just loop over the resultset, do you get results being processed even though oci_num_rows() returns 0? Sounds like you've found a bug in the oci driver

Comment: yes, althogh I get 0 for `oci_num_rows($query)`, the resultset is processed well and displayed in my applicaiton

Comment: Any idea? Am I on the right way!!?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the same query twice, I convined myself of writing a much lighter query only to count the number of the resulting rows.

```
$numrows = oci_execute($count_query); // The query return 5

if($numrows>0){

    oci_execute($select_query);
    // More code here
}else{
//do something else
}
```